# How to fix 'jumping to top of each item' while scrolling up in Flutter ListView of FutureBuilder items?

Tags: flutter, stream, httprequest, future, flutter-listview

I just started learning Flutter through a course and one of the projects is to code a **Hacker News reader** app. Two HTTP requests are needed, one to get the top list of ids and one for each article using its id.

Contrary to Google's **The Boring Show** version, I need to be able to request each article as the user scrolls down to the total number of top articles (~500). I also wanted to try a simpler way than the many streams, transformers, and workarounds that were used in my course.

I'm using a `StreamBuilder` to get the top ids from a stream through a `bloc` and a `FutureBuilder` for each row of a `ListView.builder` where the article is fetched from that `bloc`. The data is either pulled from an HTTP request or a cache (a sqflite database).

It works perfectly while scrolling down but, when scrolling up, it jumps to the top of each item except for the first 4 items (because they're already built at that point).

I've tried different structures and patterns for days and it always behaves the same way whenever I use a `FutureBuilder` inside the `ListView.builder`.
Tried it in the emulator and on my Pixel 3 XL in debug and release mode.

**The Boring Show** method of sending a limited number of articles from a `StreamBuilder` to a `ListView.builder` works because a `FutureBuilder` is not needed but there is no way to fetch more articles.

By the way, from what I can tell, the items are NOT re-fetched while scrolling up even though `ConnectionState` is set to `waiting` for every build.

I've added a video of the issue on YouTube. Hope it works:

[YouTube Video of ListView issue while scrolling up](https://youtu.be/-HB8AbWZ96Q)

Here is the class where the list is displayed. I combined the widgets to make it compact:

```
class TopList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final StoriesBloc bloc = StoriesProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
        stream: bloc.topList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return FutureBuilder<ItemModel>(
                        key: Key(snapshot.data[index].toString()),
                        future: bloc.getNewsItem(snapshot.data[index]),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                            case ConnectionState.none:
                            case ConnectionState.active:
                            case ConnectionState.waiting:
                              print('${snapshot.connectionState} for $index');
                              return Text('Loading...');
                            case ConnectionState.done:
                              return buildItem(snapshot.data, index);
                          }
                        });
                  },
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        });
  }

  Widget buildItem(ItemModel item, int index) {
    print('Building row $index');
    return ListTile(
      key: Key(index.toString()),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text('${index + 1}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
        radius: 16,
      ),
      title: Text(item.title),
      subtitle: Text('${item.score}'),
      trailing: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.comment),
          Text('${item.descendants}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

from `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.5.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.32.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I expected scrolling up and down to be smooth and a 'Loading...' text to show up for items that are loading.

Here are print outputs of activities while scrolling down than up:

```
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 17
I/flutter (13405): Building row 17
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 18
I/flutter (13405): Building row 18
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 19
I/flutter (13405): Building row 19
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 20
I/flutter (13405): Building row 20
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 21
I/flutter (13405): Building row 21
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 22
I/flutter (13405): Building row 22
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 23
I/flutter (13405): Building row 23
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 6
I/flutter (13405): Building row 6
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 5
I/flutter (13405): Building row 5
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 4
I/flutter (13405): Building row 4
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 3
I/flutter (13405): Building row 3
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 2
I/flutter (13405): Building row 2
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 1
I/flutter (13405): Building row 1
I/flutter (13405): ConnectionState.waiting for 0
I/flutter (13405): Building row 0
```

The problem might be obvious but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a ListView.builder widget. Is the only solution the one you posted below and have a dummy ListView at the same time?

Comment: Sorry @DennisAshford, I'm only now seeing your comment. Flutter has changed a lot since this post. However, displaying each ListTile with dummy data while your data is loading is common practice. There are even plugins you can use for a loading shimmer effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

Alright, got a suggestion from 'buy dip kek' at the flutter Discord group to place the exact same widget, a ListTile, with dummy data while the future from each FutureBuilder is loading. That fixed the issue.

Comment: Actually, it must be a better solution for this ... I didn't found any yet.